# PHP While loop order

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I am trying to make a follower post kind of thing in PHP and whenever Ajax refreshes my page, they are not in the correct order. The output I am getting is that the content of a post always sticks to whoever posts it, for example if I post something, then someone else posts something, then I post something again, it should be like this my post, their post, my post, instead it is like this, my post, my post, their post. So I am basically having an issue ordering what is coming out of the while loop. Here is the code I have.

```
<?php

require("scripts/connect.php");
session_start();
$my_id = $_SESSION["wave"]["id"];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `follows` WHERE `follower_id` = '$my_id'")or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($query) >= 1)
{

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {   

        $following = $row["following_id"];
        $new_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `user_id` = '$following' ORDER by `id` DESC");

        while($new_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($new_query))
        {


            echo $new_row["username"]."<br />".$new_row["content"]."<hr>";

        }

    }


}else
{

    echo "You are not following anyone; There are no new Ripples for you.";

}


?>
```

Comment: `order by dateandtime`

Comment: does your 'posts' table have a date submitted field you could sort by in the query?

Comment: @NathanielWendt, no, I didn't think it would make much of a difference since the ID's are different by a space of 2 like ID 1 and 3, yet they still end up together.

Comment: if you dont have date and time field then `order by id desc`

Comment: @Feroz Akbar I had that before I just pressed control Z on some changes I did I thought would work and pressed it to far I guess, it didn't work even when it had that.

Comment: It looks like you are using WordPress and It's been a while since I"ve used it so I looked up the 'posts' table and it looks like you have a post_date field which is actually a DATETIME value that you could sort by

Comment: @NathanielWendt I'm not using Wordpress actually XD I'm using XAMPP and Notepad++, I'm trying to create sort a social site or something along those lines and I just came across this and it has me stumped.

Comment: The problem is you are doing queries in a loop. Use a join in the first query and order it there the way you want it.

Comment: looks like @jeroen is correct, I completely missed that.